# What happens in your brain when you see a dinosaur in this stenographic image?

Tags: perception, vision, eeg, optical-illusion

You might have come across stereographic Images like the one shown below (found [here](http://www.aolej.com/stereox/img//stereo/dino.JPG)):

[image]

- What happens in your brain when you observe the dinosaur? (as you put your face on the image by touching your nose and then slowly withdrawing from the image.)
- Is this perception a particular trick that my eye performs or is it processing the visual data in an alternative way?
- Is the effect of this percept measurable by an EEG?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The source I have quoted below gives an example of the following stenographic image:-

[image: Stenographic image quoted in source article]

**Is this perception a particular trick that my eye performs or is it processing the visual data in an alternative way?**

> Stereograms can be viewed as three-dimensional images by providing two
>   side-by-side views of a three-dimensional scene, rendered from
>   slightly different viewpoints. Stereoscopes facilitate focusing of the
>   eyes depths other than the surface of a two-dimensional stereogram
>   image, allowing the two separate images to overlap in the center of
>   the field of vision (Kimmel, 2002). Once the correct depth is
>   achieved, it may seem to the viewer as if the two images are different
>   due to the horizontal retinal disparities. Then the two images can
>   fuse into a coherent three- dimensional percept where horizontal
>   disparities in the images provide important depth cues.

[image: Perception of Stenographic Images]

**Is the effect of this percept measurable by an EEG?**

> Autostereograms have been used in recent research to investigate
>   three-dimensional depth perception. These efforts have improved
>   understanding of the various visual cues involved in forming
>   three-dimensional percepts, perceiving motion in depth, attention-
>   switching in the depth of field, and the neural correlates of forming
>   and maintaining a unified three-dimensional structure in awareness.
>
> Revonsuo and colleagues (Revonsuo, et al., 1997) used neural
>   synchronization to investigate the neural correlates of
>   three-dimensional percept formations. They confirmed that
>   autostereoscopic perception is primarily mediated by right
>   parieto-temporal activity. Their research indicated a region of
>   synchrony spanning portions of the right temporal, parietal and
>   occipital lobes, with maximum power in the gamma (36-44Hz) frequency
>   range. Also employing electroencephalogram (EEG) recording, Burgess,
>   Rehman, and Williams (2003) located particular brain regions,
>   including the left frontal (F7) and the right and midline occipital
>   (Oz, O2) clusters, exhibiting functional clustering during
>   autostereoscopic perception. Overall, neural complexity was highest
>   with the most functional clustering of responses during observer
>   awareness of the three-dimensional object. Additional clustering
>   analyses revealed functional clusters of scalp recordings in the
>   aforementioned areas that correlated with both phases of
>   three-dimensional perception (search to three-dimensional and
>   three-dimensional maintenance).

---

**Sources**

- [Autostereograms and Autostereoscopic Perception](http://cognitrn.psych.indiana.edu/busey/q551/Phenomenology/Neural%20Correlates%20of%20Autostereopsis.pdf) 
  **Authors:** Leslie Blaha, Christopher Honey, and Eric Nichols 
  **Date:** October 31, 2005
- Burgess, A.P., Rehman, J., & Williams, J.D. (2003). *[Changes in neural complexity during the perception of three-dimensional images using random dot stereograms](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167876003000023?np=y)*. International Journal of Psychophysiology, 48, 35-42.
- Kimmel, R. (2002). *[Three-dimensional shape reconstruction from autostereograms and stereo](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ron/PAPERS/autostereograms2002.pdf)*. Journal of Visual Communication and Image Representation, 13, 324-333.